# Users with friends query in SQL

Tags: sql

I have to tables in my database.

**Users**

```
 - id
 - username
```

**Friends**

```
 - user_id (invitor)
 - friend_id (that get invitation)
 - accepted
```

Now If user #1 invites user #2 to be a friend and #2 accepts, I want user 2 displayed on user 1's site, and user 1 on user 2's site.

I can't figure out how the query for this should look like.

How can I write a query to return the user and their friends in the same SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT users.username FROM users, friends WHERE friends.accepted = 1 AND friends.user_id = ... AND friends.friend_id = users.id` ?

Comment: Shouldn't `users, friends` be `users inner join friends` or am I just thinking of T-SQL? I think "comma joins" (or whatever they're called) are depreciated in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the id of the user you are showing the page from is 5:

for the friends the user invited:

```
SELECT username 
FROM users, friends
WHERE id = friend_id AND user_id = 5 AND accepted = 1
```

for the friends which send the invitation to the user

```
SELECT username 
FROM users, friends 
WHERE id = user_id AND friend_id = 5 AND accepted = 1
```

In one query:

```
SELECT username 
FROM users, friends 
WHERE 
  (      
    (id = friend_id AND user_id = 5)
    OR
    (id = user_id AND friend_id = 5)
  )
  AND accepted = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I think this will work for you...

For user 2 to appear on user 1 page...

```
SELECT U.ID, U.UserName
FROM Friends F
INNER JOIN Users U ON F.Friend_ID = U.ID
WHERE
  F.User_ID = [User 1 ID]
  AND F.Accepted = [True|1]
```

For user 1 to appear on user 2 page...

```
SELECT U.ID, U.UserName
FROM Friends F
INNER JOIN Users U ON F.User_ID = U.ID
WHERE
  F.Friend_ID = [User 2 ID]
  AND F.Accepted = [True|1]
```

You'll have to replace the bracketed values with what applies in your database...